# How do I verify that my SCXML defines a valid state machine?

Tags: java, scxml

I've just started looking at defining state machines and [SCXML](http://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/) looks attractive, especially the [Apache Commons SCXML for Java](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-scxml/). Obviously I can validate the XML (with an appropriate XSD).

However I can't obviously find any way to verify that the defined state machine is valid (no dead-ends, no unreachable states, etc).

But how can I verify a defined state-machine before I execute it? 
In particular I am interested in tools that can integrated into a build tool-chain (i.e. from the command-line).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The uscxml-analyze tool from the [uSCXML](https://github.com/tklab-tud/uscxml) distribution will do just that:

```
$ uscxml-browser -c ../../test/w3c/ecma/test144.scxml
```

It checks for a whole bunch of [issues](https://github.com/tklab-tud/uscxml/blob/master/src/uscxml/debug/InterpreterIssue.cpp#L94):

- Required attributes
- Valid parent elements
- Valid default history configurations
- Valid initial transition
- Valid initial attributes
- Unreachable state hierarchies
- Uniqueness of state id attribute
- Valid targets for transitions
- Redundant / unselectable transitions
- Superfluous history elements
- Legal configuration of target sets
- A bunch of attribute / element combination constraints
- Valid syntax of data-model expressions

The uSCXML interpreter will also check for cycles within a macro-step during interpretation.